# glxgears doesn't work

Tags: system-installation

I have just started using Ubuntu 18.04 in command prompt. During the initial installation in Windows 11, I could get glxgears to work. Now when I type, nothing happens. It just goes to the next line and nothing opens up.

Comment: You might need to reinstall `mesa-utils` to reinstall glxgears.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=glxgears  `sudo apt install --reinstall mesa-utils`